# boostrap division size relative to an otherone

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a **right division** that has the **size of the browser window** (100vh).

The **left division** is compsed of 2 divisions that can have variable sizes but all together should have the same size of the left division.
The bottom of the scroll bar should always end at the bottom of the browser window such as on the example below:

[image]

I can't find how to set the left division to match this pattern.

Here is a Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bb61c412/67/

And the code:

```css
#left-div {
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: white;
}

#right-div {
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: gray;
}

#scroll{
   padding-right:0px; 
   padding-left:0px; 
   background-color:#FAFAFA;
   overflow-y:scroll;
   height:70vh;  
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://bootswatch.com/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />


<div class="col-sm-7" id='left-div'>

  <div style="background-color:#FAFAFA;width:100%;height:100%;">

    <div style="height:100px;background-color:white">
    </div>

    <div id="scroll">

      <p>
        "Sed ut...."
      </p>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-5" id='right-div'>
</div>



<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you be more precise by telling us what are you getting when you run the code ? It works fine for me.

Comment: Well right now I have arbitrarily setted up the scroll bar div to 70vh. But it is not automatically rezising in the way that the scroll bottom is always at the bottom of the page for any browser window size.

Comment: Do you mean that there is a blank space under the scroll ?

Comment: Yes. Now it is fixed to 70vh so it will only have no space for a certain window size and will not adapt itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to do this is using [flex-boxes](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and the `align-self`property :

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bb61c412/94/)

```css
#left-div {
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: white;
}

#right-div {
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: gray;
}

#scroll{
   
   padding-right:0px; 
   padding-left:0px; 
   background-color:#CCC;
   overflow-y:scroll;
   height:70vh; 
   align-self:flex-end; /* Flex-end to get your scroll down */
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-7" id='left-div'>
  
  <!-- Setting the main container to display : flex -->
  <div style="display:flex;background-color:#FAFAFA;width:100%;height:100%;">

    <div style="height:100px;background-color:white">
    </div>

    <div id="scroll">

      <p>
        Lorem ipsum...
      </p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-5" id='right-div'>
</div>
```

**UPDATE :**

Another solution is to set your container's position to `relative` and your scroll div to `absolute`. From there, you can make your scroll div stick to the bottom by setting the `bottom`attribute to 0.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bb61c412/108/)

```css
#left-div {
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: white;
}

#right-div {
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: gray;
}

#scroll{
   
   padding-right:0px; 
   padding-left:0px; 
   background-color:#CCC;
   overflow-y:scroll;
   height:70vh; 
   width:100%;
   position:absolute;
   bottom :0;
}

.form-inline {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-7" id='left-div'>
  
  <!-- Setting the main container's position to relative -->
  <div style="postion:relative;background-color:#FAFAFA;width:100%;height:100%;">
  

    <div style="height:100px;background-color:white">
        <form >
    <div class=form-inline style='text-align:center;'>
    <select name="Form1" class="form-control" >
                <option value="0">Form1</option>
                <option value="1">Option2</option>
                <option value="2">Option3</option>
    </select>
    
    <select name="Form2" class="form-control" >
                <option value="0">Form2</option>
                <option value="1">Option2</option>
                <option value="2">Option3</option>
    </select>
    
    <select name="Form3" class="form-control" >
                <option value="0">Form3</option>
                <option value="1">Option2</option>
                <option value="2">Option3</option>
    </select>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>

    </div>  
    </form>
    </div>

    <div id="scroll">


    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-5" id='right-div'>
</div>
```

Comment: The display flex works well in the case of a simple paragraph as on the example, but the problem is that it completely messes up all the display of other elements in the division such as forms, other sub-division etc. Doesent it give something less invasive? ps: the fiddle in your post is not updated with your code.

Comment: Can you provide the full code ? It's hard to find an answer that suits your problem if we don't have all the parameters. PS : updated the fiddle

Comment: Here is an example:https://jsfiddle.net/bb61c412/105/, you can see the difference with and without 'display:flex' on the Form display.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it works perfectly!

Comment: I'd maybe have a last question on this topic: for some sreen sizes, some of the Forms from the top left div disapear behind the bottom left div. Would it give a way so that the top left div expends instead of being hidden behind the bottom one?

Comment: Maybe something like #scroll{min-height=40vh} but it doesent seem to make a difference to have min-height or height: it always displays the height specified instead od adapting the height  to the size of the division above.

Comment: Hmm I can't think of a CSS way to do so. You may have to use javascript.